# CSS Pattern Image Border

Tags: css, design-patterns, geometry, border-image

[(This is What I did)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlR03.png) 
[(This is What I want)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjIgJ.jpg)

How can I do the round patterned border-image around the red circle in the image in a valid way with the standard?

Need some good suggestion.

Regards

Comment: http://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/Circular-Percentage-Loader-Plugin-with-jQuery-Canvas-ClassyLoader.html

Comment: http://circle.firchow.net/

Comment: Google it and you will find more

Comment: I have done this already with http://anthonyterrien.com/demo/knob/

What I want to know is just the trick to do the patterned border around the circle with CSS.

Comment: Please post your code, so someone can help you

Comment: This code is auto generated by jQuery Plugin (Knob) with Canvas. 

I had an idea to do it like .canvas:after {} But it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this [LINK](https://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/) for pattern. Create pattern what you like. If you have any queries, please comment.

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( to right, #f6ba52, #f6ba52 10px, #ffd180 10px, #ffd180 20px);
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.circle:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  content: "";
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```